# Recieve feedback that a user has input into your android app?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've created a very simple movie review app that has a top ten movies of all time. Know that this will be a very controversial topic with lots of different opinions i have created a EditText Box where an user can input there favorite film. What I'm wondering is how can i save this information to view it so that i can make changes to the list according to users preferences etc.

Comment: If it is few inputs, you can use `SharedPreferences` to store the value in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case I suggest using [Sqlite Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) and of course you can use [SharedPrefrences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to save that but its a key-value pair.